# FFMPEG convert file output without original file's extension

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

```
@echo off

rem echo %~F0
rem echo %~F1

Set filename=%~F0
For %%A in ("%filename%") do (
    Set Folder=%%~dpA
    Set Name=%%~nxA
)

Set filename1=%~F1
For %%B in ("%filename1%") do (
    Set Folder1=%%~dpB
    Set Name1=%%~nxB
)

rem echo "%Folder1%"
rem echo "%Name1%"
rem pause

cd "%Folder1%"

TITLE Mp4 Video 1 Click - FFMPEG v.4.2.2 32-bit - Encode to HLS (software libx264)

set PATH=%Folder%;%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32


ffmpeg.exe -i "%Name1%" -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls "%Name1%.m3u8"
```

Comment: `Set "BaseName1=%%~nB"`, and `"%BaseName1%.m3u8"` should be a quick fix.

Comment: can u pls guide me where to update this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should need for this task is a single line batch file:

```batch-file
@Start "Mp4 Video 1 Click - FFMPEG v.4.2.2 32-bit - Encode to HLS (software libx264)" /D "%~dp1" "%~dp0ffmpeg.exe" -i "%~nx1" -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls "%~n1.m3u8"
```

You can simply drag and drop your `.mp4` file onto it, or enter it as the first argument in `cmd.exe`.

Comment: is it possible to forks it with two option? 1) creating a folder with same name and move it to the folder 2) create specified folder and add move the output into it??

Comment: I feel that I've more than answered your initial question, @sknagu05, by providing a much better, and more compact, solution. Unfortunately, that does not tie me into a support service deal with you, so new questions, should be considered for, well, new questions. However, please be careful that your questions are less about a single piece of software which accepts command line arguments, _(which are more suited to [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/ask))_, than they are about programming.

Comment: Im sorry for posting back questions even after getting the answer in first instance. Thank you again